# How to create a non-nullable dummy field for data-type geography, geometry, image, and XML in SELECT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017

I'm creating table-valued dummy-functions.

To create all the fields, I just generate them as

```
SELECT 
      CAST(NULL AS <datatype>) AS AliasColumn1 
     ,CAST(NULL AS <datatype>) AS AliasColumn2
     ,...
```

e.g.

```
SELECT 
      CAST(NULL AS int) AS Field1 
     ,CAST(NULL AS nvarchar(MAX)) AS Field2
```

That way, I don't have to get dependencies right when I create all functions/tables/views/etc. 

Now this works fine, except it returns wrong nullability. 
So I'm trying to generate a valid dummy-field as **non-nullable** value.
To do that, I just wrap the NULL into a ISNULL.

This works fine for almost all data-types, except geography, geometry, image and XML. 
Is it at all possible to create a non-nullable geography|geometry|image|XML-field in a select/view ?

No matter what I tried, geography, geometry, image, xml stays on NULLABLE:yes...
This is what I have been doing so far

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dbo.TestTypes;
GO



CREATE VIEW dbo.TestTypes
AS
SELECT 
     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS foo 

     /*
    ,CAST(NULL AS int) AS Field1 
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS int), '123') AS Field2 
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS int), 'A') AS Field2_Error 
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS decimal(5,2)), '123.456') AS Field3 
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS bit), '123') AS Field4 
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS float), '123') AS Field5 
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS char), '123') AS Field6 
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS text), '123') AS Field7 
     */
     /*
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS bigint), '20190101') AS Field1
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS binary), 0) AS Field2
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS bit), '20190101') AS Field3
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS char), '20190101') AS Field4
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS date), '20190101') AS Field5
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS datetime), '20190101') AS Field6
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS datetime2), '20190101') AS Field7
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset), '20190101') AS Field8
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS decimal), 0) AS Field9
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS float), '20190101') AS Field10
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS geography), 'POLYGON EMPTY') AS Field11
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS geometry), 'POLYGON EMPTY') AS Field12
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS hierarchyid), CAST('/0/' AS hierarchyid)) AS Field13
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS image), '20190101') AS Field14
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS int), '20190101') AS Field15
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS money), '20190101') AS Field16
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS nchar), '20190101') AS Field17
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS ntext), '20190101') AS Field18
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS numeric), 0) AS Field19
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS nvarchar), '20190101') AS Field20
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS real), '20190101') AS Field21
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS smalldatetime), '20190101') AS Field22
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS smallint), 0) AS Field23
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS smallmoney), 0) AS Field24
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS sql_variant), '20190101') AS Field25
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS sysname), '20190101') AS Field26
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS text), '20190101') AS Field27
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS time), '20190101') AS Field28
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS timestamp), 0) AS Field29
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS tinyint), 0) AS Field30
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS uniqueidentifier), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') AS Field31
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS varbinary), 0) AS Field32
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS varchar), '20190101') AS Field33
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS xml), '20190101') AS Field34
    */


    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS geography), 'POLYGON EMPTY') AS Field11
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS geography), 'POLYGON((1 1, 3 3, 3 1, 1 1))') AS Field11a
    ,CAST('POLYGON EMPTY' AS geography) AS Field11B

    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS geometry), 'POLYGON EMPTY') AS Field12
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS geometry), 'POLYGON((1 1, 3 3, 3 1, 1 1))') AS Field12a
    ,CAST('POLYGON EMPTY' AS geometry) AS Field12B
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS image), '20190101') AS Field14
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS image), 0x123567AB) AS Field14A
    ,CAST(0x123567AB AS image) AS Field14B
    ,ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS xml), CAST('<h1>Test</h1>' AS xml)) AS Field34
    , CAST('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><html></html>' AS xml) AS Field34A

GO


--geography
--geometry
--image
--xml
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'TestTypes' 
-- SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'Table_1' 

/*
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT TOP 999999999 name, CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS varchar(20)) AS rn
    FROM sys.types WHERE is_user_defined = 0 ORDER BY name 
)
SELECT 
     name 
    ,
    CASE 
        WHEN name = 'uniqueidentifier' THEN '   SELECT ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS uniqueidentifier), ''00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'') AS Field' + rn 
        WHEN name = 'hierarchyid' THEN  '   SELECT ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS ' + name + '), CAST(''/0/'' AS hierarchyid)) AS Field' + rn 
        WHEN name IN ('geography', 'geometry') THEN  '  SELECT ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS ' + name + '), ''POLYGON EMPTY'') AS Field' + rn 
        WHEN name IN ('tinyint', 'smallmoney', 'smallint', 'numeric', 'decimal', 'binary', 'varbinary', 'timestamp') THEN  '    SELECT ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS ' + name + '), 0) AS Field' + rn 
        ELSE '  SELECT ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS ' + name + '), ''20190101'') AS Field' + rn 
    END AS sql2 
FROM CTE 
*/
```

Comment: Because your view isn't selecting from persisted table columns SQL Server treats its columns like computed columns. *"The result of most expressions is considered nullable even if only nonnullable columns are present, because possible underflows or overflows will produce null results as well."*, ref: [Computed Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms191250(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: And how do you want to produce an underflow or an overflow with the xml or the geography data type ? Also, why does it work with integers, then ?

Comment: In fact, `ISNULL` and `COALESCE` are the only expressions that will allow SQL Server to "see" a computed expression as definitely not `NULL`. All other constructs, no matter how trivial, will tag the resulting expression as nullable. It's interesting and inconsistent that this applies to all data types save for the ones mentioned in this question.

Comment: How come `create view dbo.TestTypes as select [int]=cast(0 as int)` reports as `is_nullable=true` then? Under what circumstance can `0` be `null`? The `isnull()` trick is exploiting a buggy behavior.

Comment: @AlwaysLeaning: Nope, it's using [documented behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql). "An expression that is nullable can be turned into a nonnullable one by specifying `ISNULL` with the `check_expression` constant, where the constant is a nonnull value substituted for any `NULL` result." The fact that this doesn't work for the CLR types is anomalous but possibly defensible; the fact that it doesn't work for `image` is a real anomaly.

Comment: Hypothesis: this happens because there are no constant literals for these types; every attempt to declare one involves some implicit conversion, which in turn is deemed "possibly `NULL`". The same is technically true for `DATETIME`, `DATETIME2` and `DATETIMEOFFSET` (these always involve implicit conversions from strings) which would counter this argument, but on the other hand the engine has special logic for these.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to create new table with these types not nullable and referring them in the views as many times as you need.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.DummyDataHelper;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.DummyDataHelper
(
     geographyNotNULL   geography NOT NULL
    ,geometryNotNULL    geometry NOT NULL
    ,imageNotNULL   image NOT NULL
);

GO

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dbo.TestTypes;
GO





CREATE VIEW dbo.TestTypes
AS
SELECT 
     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS foo 


    ,geographyNotNULL AS Field11
    ,geographyNotNULL AS Field11a
    ,geographyNotNULL AS Field11B
    ,geometryNotNULL AS Field12
    ,geometryNotNULL  AS Field12a
    ,geometryNotNULL AS Field12B
    ,imageNotNULL AS Field14
    ,imageNotNULL AS Field14A
    ,imageNotNULL AS Field14B

FROM dbo.DummyDataHelper

GO


SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'TestTypes'
```